# Can colons be used to indicate a consequence?

Tags: punctuation, colons

I wonder whether colons may be used to indicate a consequence.

Example:

1. Texts usually appear in sequence**:** using information from preceding texts may improve the classification accuracy.
2. Texts usually appear in sequence**, therefore** using information from preceding texts may improve the classification accuracy.

Are the two forms correct, or is only the second one correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a colon when the second phrase of a sentence is directly related to the first phrase. The most important rule regarding colons is that the first phrase must be able to stand as a sentence on its own. So both of your sentences are valid.

The thing about punctuation is that can be multiple options. Here, you could use a colon (:), a semi-colon (;), or a period (.), and start a new sentence with the second phrase. It's up to the writer what to use, and it has little or no effect on the meaning. In the US, the most popular option would be to start a new sentence, but that's because colons are out of fashion for most styles of writing in the US.

> Texts usually appear in sequence: using information from preceding
>   texts may improve the classification accuracy.
>
> Texts usually appear in sequence; using information from preceding
>   texts may improve the classification accuracy.
>
> Texts usually appear in sequence. Using information from preceding
>   texts may improve the classification accuracy.

Comment: A fourth option is to use a comma and a conjunction, like "... sequence, and using ..." As OP includes in the question. Yes, that's also valid.

Comment: If you start giving options that add words, it never ends :-).

Comment: In a sense, sure. But I've always figured that if you have two independent clauses, there are four basic options: separate sentences, colon, semi-colon, or comma plus conjunction. Sure, you could completely re-word them, and at that point all bets are off.